# How can I determine which DataTemplate to use for ToolTips?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a `ResourceDictionary` with several `DataTemplate`s that will be used to display classes with the following property:

```
    public MyToolTip ToolTip {get;}
```

And within the `DataTemplate`s several controls will bind their `ToolTip` property to this property.

The `ResourceDictionary` also contains this (demo) `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="models:MyToolTip">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}"/> <!-- MyToolTip class has a Details property -->
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

How can I - at the ResourceDictionary's root level - declare that whenever a `MyToolTip` instance is displayed, the above `DataTemplate` shall be used?

Comment: Not enough information here.  What is `MyToolTip`?  Show us the class/control.    Moreover why do you need a custom class for a tooltip?

Comment: Instead of building a `DataTemplate` whose `DataType` is `MyToolTip`, it might be a better idea to build a `DataTemplate` for each class you currently have exposing a property of type `MyToolTip`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses! Apparently what I was trying isn't really possible. "Auto-magic" DataTemplate selection is not supported for "normal" Xaml properties.

I did manage to get this far:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyToolTipDataTemplate">
    <Grid Background="DarkOliveGreen" Width="200" Height="100">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type editors:SliderEditor}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyToolTipDataTemplate}" Content="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Using the `Style` I was able to change the `ToolTip` property, but `Style` will not work for derived classes, i.e. I would need to implement the styles with the correct `TargetType` for every possible type. And, I initially wanted to determine how *any* `ToolTip` of *any* control is rendered, if it's value is `MyToolTip`.

But, in this case, setting the `ToolTip` to the outermost element (e.g. `SliderEditor`) is ok, any nested controls would have shown the same tool tip, anyway.

Also, in this case, since all editors derived from one base class, I decided to do the following, because it spared me from editing all Xaml files.

Instead of a `DataTemplate` I implemented a new `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Demo.MyToolTipControl">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ToolTip.Text}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the ctor of the base class, I added:

```
this.ToolTip = new MyToolTipControl();
```

Note: I tried letting the `ContentControl` "auto-magically" detect the correct `DataTemplate` (that then still had a `DataType`), like @Joe suggested in the comments, but that didn't work. Maybe just some little mistake; since I'd opted for a different approach I didn't spend any more time finding out why.